# Does the expression $\frac{\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T}{\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v}}$ have a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, transpose

I have encountered the matrix $$\frac{\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T}{\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v}}$$ (where $\mathbf{v}$ is a column-vector) a several times when differentiating vector expressions and was wondering whether it has a name.

Comment: This dayadic is the projector on the (normalized) vector $\displaystyle \frac{\mathbf v}{|\mathbf v|}$, since $\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v}$ equals the square of $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T$ is the its dyadic product with its self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the matrix representing projection onto $v$.

Comment: Orthogonal projection onto the span of $v$, rather.

Comment: I think there is no difference.